# What is the proper way to use EditText content change listener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Am trying to do something when my EditText content is changed.

Here is 3 ways i find to do it.

### 1.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener {
    //my code
}
```

2. 

---

```
edittext.doAfterTextChanged {
    //my code
}
```

3. 

---

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        //my code
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
})
```

All works perfectly for my purpose. Can somebody explain if there is any difference between each of them, any advantage or disadvantage using a particular way or simply all of them same?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Kotlin, but in Java only the 3rd way is valid. Also, I'm not sure how option 1 is even possible since you're not passing anything as the listener. Option 2 was probably added in Kotlin to make it easier since you only usually need that method from these 3 given in option 3.

Comment: Depends what exactly you are trying to do .  I think the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) has it all ..

Answer (score 2):

1 and 3 are basically same thing. In kotling `object : TextWatcher` is not needed as it can wrap the implementation with lambda using just `{}`

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener {
    //my code
}
```

What you did in the 3 with `object : TextWatcher` is same thing but the implemented functions `afterTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` are visible.

And for 2, android in kotlin gives an inline function `edittext.doAfterTextChanged` which just does everything for you what you did on 3 using `object : TextWatcher` under the hood and gives access to only `afterTextChanged` functions implementation. This code is from `androidx.core.widget` package which shows what it's doing under the hood:

```
inline fun TextView.doAfterTextChanged(
    crossinline action: (text: Editable?) -> Unit
) = addTextChangedListener(afterTextChanged = action)
```